# Do canonical LINQ queries guard against N+1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With lazy loading used by default, I know that you should call .Include() on your Entity Framework entities to pull in associated entities you want in your queries to reduce the number of calls to the db if you're calling LINQ methods on your entities. If you don't, you run the risk of repeated database calls for each row (the N+1 problem)

Can someone confirm that if I write a canonical LINQ query, with the joins defined explicitly, that we guard against N+1?

```
from x in _context.tblOrder
join y in _context.tblCustomer equals y.id = x.customerId
select x
```

Is there any way N+1 could creep in when we're loading in all the required entities with joins?

*EDIT*

As background, someone asked how junior developers could guard against N+1. I mentioned the simplest way would be to write out your queries and define your joins, I want confirmation that was I indicated was 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are really asking is

> Will this query hit the database once?

Then the answer is yes. LINQ to EF translates your expression to raw SQL and only when you evaluate the query will it send anything to the database e.g. `ToList()`/`foreach`/`for` etc. and once that query is sent nothing else is unless you explicitly tell it otherwise.

Your LINQ statement could be simplified using a Lambda expression e.g.

```
_context.tblOrder.Include("Customer").ToList();
```

This would give you all the order details, including all related customer details, in a single database trip.

Comment: Technically, the query is not sent to the database until it is iterated over (when the `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` is called) which would be in a `foreach` (like in the `List<T>` constructor). Select itself isn't materializing a query.

Comment: @SimonBelanger it doesn't if it's an `IQueryable` collection, however, AFAIK `Select()` *can* trigger a DB call if your iterating over an `IEumerable`. I didn't want to get into the specifics of when it does or doesn't depending on the implementation detail, just giving some examples of when it could potentially trigger a DB trip.

Comment: It does because it will iterate and yield. The differences between the `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` versions are important. I agree with your answer and points, but I think the distinction is important.

Comment: @SimonBelanger sure I agree, will remove it to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you specify tables in a join doesn't mean that you can't run into a n+1 issue when you iterate over the values. Consider the following extension to your query:

```
var query = from o in Orders
            join c in Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
            select o;

foreach (var o in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", o.OrderDate, o.Employee.FirstName));
}
```

In this case, each time you navigate through the order's Employee object, the employee is fetched from the database for that order. If you wanted to avoid the issue, you could project the values you want in the select clause:

```
var query = from o in Orders
            join c in Customers on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
            select new {o.OrderDate, o.Employee.FirstName};

foreach (var o in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}", o.OrderDate, o.FirstName));
}
```

Note, in this case, you don't even need the join as you can just use the navigation properties instead. Of course, if you don't allow navigation properties in your entities and rely only on joins, you can avoid the n+1 situation, but that is not a very OOP way of solving the problem.

I think you would be safe guaranteeing against n+1 if you only return anonymous types from your queries, but that would be rather restrictive as well.

The best option is to make sure to profile your application's generated SQL and know precisely when and why you are hitting the database. I discuss some of the profilers available at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Database-Performance-hints.